# Error when passing dictionary between view controllers: [__SwiftValue renderingMode]:

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary

I am trying to pass a data through a dictionary via NotificationCenter. Here is my code.

SearchViewController:

```
func addBook() {
    let selectedBook = ["title": "A Guide to Bugs"]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Pass.Book"), object: nil, userInfo: selectedBook])
}

@IBAction func goBack(_ sender: Any) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

MainViewController:

```
var book: [String: String]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reload(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name("Pass.Book"), object: nil)
}

@objc func reload(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    let passedBook = ["title": (notification.userInfo?["title"] as! String)]
    self.book = passedBook
    self.settingsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

The line `self.book = passedBook` is what is causing the problem. For some reason, the code is not being able to assign the passed dictionary to the dictionary initialized when the view was loaded and it gives me this error.

> [__SwiftValue renderingMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000013c6d00
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__SwiftValue renderingMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003f78780'
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Does anyone know how to fix this bug? Is it a problem with my code or an Xcode bug?

Comment: ***Is it a problem with my code or an Xcode bug?*** Very likely your code. But the code in your post is too simplified and hard to show how to fix. Your `selectedBook` in `addBook()` lacks "thumbnail" or "previewLink", all such things may affect. Please show exact code which causes your issue.

Comment: As @OOPer said, you need to provide more detail. The code you posted won't even compile... you have an extraneous `]` in your `.post(...)` line. After removing that `]` and doing a quick test based on what you've provided, I get no error.